# Show/hide another input fields using h:selectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I am using JSF2 and Java to build a web application. I want to build a form like the one at the picture below:

[image]

When somebody unchecks the checkbox the form should disappear:
[image]

[Here](http://www.sencha.com/examples/pages/forms/forms.html) is an example with gwt.

---

So far,
I tried some stuff with the `<f:ajax>` tag and an `PropertyActionListener` in the managedBean but it didn't work. Can somebody give me an example or at least some hints to accomplish my goal. I would be really thankfull

Comment: lol, added this question and the first viewer rates it -1 without giving a comment -.-

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `<f:ajax render="idOfPanelContainingInputFields">` in the checkbox and give the component containing the input fields a `rendered` attribute which depends on the checkbox's state. No need for another JS code clutter.

```
<h:form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox binding="#{showUserInfo}">
                <f:ajax render="idOfPanelContainingTextBox" />
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            <h:outputText value="User information" />
        </legend>
        <h:panelGroup id="idOfPanelContainingTextBox" layout="block">
            <ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty showUserInfo.value and showUserInfo.value}">
                <p>
                    <h:outputLabel for="firstName" value="First name:" />
                    <h:inputText id="firstName" value="#{bean.user.firstName}" />
                </p>
            </ui:fragment>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </fieldset>
</h:form>
```

The above example binds the checkbox to the view, you can of course also bind it to a `boolean` bean property, you can then remove the `not empty` check from the `rendered` attribute.

```
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.showUserInfo}">

...

            <ui:fragment rendered="#{bean.showUserInfo}">
```

#### See also:

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo)
- [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w)

Answer (score 11):

As suggested by amorfis, the idea of using Ajax here is not the best solution, as you will do a call to your server for a client-side manipulation.

The best solution is to use Javascript to hide your component(s). For example, if all your labels and input texts are nested in a `<h:panelGrid>` component, you can do that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideOrShow(show) {
        // Get the panel using its ID
        var obj = document.getElementById("myForm:myPanel");
        if (show) {
            obj.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            obj.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>

<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="myCheckbox" onclick="hideOrShow(this.checked);"/>

    <h:panelGrid id="myPanel" columns="2">
        ...
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Comment: @Sven Maybe the `this.checked` in the `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` component is not working correctly. Need to check that and then edit my answer in consequence...

Comment: @Sven I just tried this code snippet, and everything is working on my computer (I am using JSF 1.2, but nothing JSF-specific here). Could you update your question and show your code?

Comment: Okay, works now. I missspelled an id -.-. Thank you very much for that

Comment: +1, If i could give you more than 1 vote on this post. I was also trying the same thing for so long, but I was not getting it. In this post I was trying other way as what @balusC described, but I guess that is for J2R4, but your solution worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: extremaly easy with this.checked. nice.

Comment: Even if I did not try @balusC solution, my beginner feeling is that it is easier to have this solution with javascript snippet in this simple example. Is there in stack overflow a good thread about when implementing in  back-end code versus in front-end ?

Comment: in case the default behaviour is that the checkbox is unchecked (and so the form should not be visible)  , the solution for correct initialization is to add  style="display: none"  for the panelGrid

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by jQuery, or another JavaScript. It is also possible by `<f:ajax>`, but it connects to the server, which you don't need here.

By jQuery you can just hide the form, not changing the DOM. As far as I understand, it should be enough.

Post some .xhtml if you want more :)