# Nested ajax in JSF and ui:repeat

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, facelets

```
<h:form>
    <fieldset>
        <h:selectManyListbox id="listbox" value="#{form.items}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{form.allItems}">
        </h:selectManyListbox>
    </fieldset>
    <h:commandButton value="Get Table" action="#{form.getTable}">
        <f:ajax render="result_table" execute="listbox" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:panelGrid id="result_table">
        <table>
            <thead></thead>
            <tbody>
                <ui:repeat var="table" value="#{form.resultTable}">
                    <tr>
                         <td>#{table.name}</td>
                         <td>
                             <h:selectBooleanCheckbox binding="#{showMore}">
                                 <f:ajax render="inner" />
                             </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                         </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                         <td>
                             <h:panelGrid id="inner" rendered="#{not empty showMore.value and showMore.value}">
                                 <table></table>
                             </h:panelGrid>
                         </td>
                    </tr>
                </ui:repeat>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

I followed the checkbox sample code from BalusC [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698579/show-hide-jsf2-form-using-selectbooleancheckbox/3699920#3699920).

When I click the command button, based on the list box values, it generates a table result which I display in `h:panelGrid id="result_table"`. This command button works. Inside the generated table, I have some sub-tables I want to display, but only if I check the box to show them. For the checkbox if I use `render="@form"` it collapses my outer parent table. If I use `render="inner"` checking/unchecking box does nothing.

How do I get this to work? Is it because the two ajax are in conflict?

FYI, I also tried using a bean property instead but got the same result. When I tried using the javascript method mentioned in the same link, but checking/unchecking the box has no effect.

Updated to add example snippet and `<ui:repeat></ui:repeat>` above:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox binding="#{showMore}">
     <f:ajax render="inner" />
 </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
 <h:panelGrid id="inner">
     <h:outputText value="always" />
     <h:outputText value="hidden" rendered="#{not empty showMore.value and showMore.value}" />
 </h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: I have a hard time to see the problem in the code and correlate this with your question message. Didn't you oversimplify the code snippet? I'd expect another `rendered` attribute for the `result_table` or so. Consider to post a full working [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) in flavor of a XHTML file and a managed bean which contains the minimum required necessary code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately my code is on another computer on intranet and I can't post the full code. I changed the code and re-worded the question, hopefully it's a lot clearer.

Comment: Ah right, you omitted `id="inner"` from the original example. Now it's more clear what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is here:

```
<h:panelGrid id="inner" rendered="#{not empty showMore.value and showMore.value}">
    <table></table>
</h:panelGrid>
```

The `f:ajax` uses JavaScript to locate the element-to-be-rendered in the client side. JavaScript won't be able to locate the HTML representation of the `inner` panelgrid when it's not rendered to the client side by JSF. Put the `inner` id in a parent component instead which is always rendered to the client side, so that Ajax/JavaScript can locate it regardless of the `rendered` condition. E.g.:

```
<h:panelGroup id="inner">
    <h:panelGrid rendered="#{not empty showMore.value and showMore.value}">
        <table></table>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGroup>
```

---

**Update**: as per the comments, using the `ui:repeat` should not form a problem here. Even more, to be sure I have copypasted your example to my playground environment and it works fine (using Mojarra 2.0.3 on Tomcat 6.0.29). The bean is by the way marked [`@ViewScoped`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ViewScoped.html). Maybe yours was [`@RequestScoped`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/RequestScoped.html) and the loading of the value for the `ui:repeat` was based on some request scoped condition which wasn't retained in the subsequent ajax calls?

#### See also:

- [The benefits and pitfalls of `@ViewScoped`](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html) - explains the value of `@ViewScoped`
- [What are the main disadvantages of JSF 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623911/what-are-the-main-disadvantages-of-java-server-faces-2-0) - a bit of history

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thank you. I changed the bean to `@ViewScoped` and it worked. I should read up on setting the right scope for my beans.