# How to not close Richfaces popup after sumbit?

Tags: jsf, popup, richfaces, submit

How can I prevent a popupPanel from closing after I sumbit a form inside it?

My code for button:

```
<h:commandButton value="Search" action="#{facesBean.search()}" >
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="result" />
</h:commandButton>
```

My code for the panel to be rendered after submit:

```
<h:panelGroup id="result" rendered="#{facesBean.list != null}">
TEST TO RERENDER
</h:panelGroup>
```

They're in the same h:form.

Is there something wrong? I don't get any error when running it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways:

1. Just submit the form by ajax.
2. If you can't submit by ajax for some reason, just reopen the popup panel on postback.

Comment: I tried to do it by ajax.
My action gets executed, but my table won't rerender.

How can I reopen it automatically on postback?

Comment: Just specify the table's ID in `render` attribute of ajax component. Opening on postback is to be done by specifying the `show` attribute of `<rich:popupPanel>` accordingly.

Comment: I tried that way, but it didn't worked. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I edited my main post with the code for my button and my panel to rerender.

Comment: Strangely it works if I take "rendered="#{facesBean.list != null}" out.

Comment: This is not strange. If a JSF component is not rendered, then JavaScript/Ajax can't find anything in the HTML DOM tree to update. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w/9010771#9010771 Perhaps you're confusing JSF's `rendered` attribute with CSS' `display` attribute.