# Using jQuery Mobile popup with JSF

Tags: jsf, jquery-mobile, popup

Consider the following JSF (& jQuery Mobile) markup:

```
<h:form>

            <a href="#login" data-rel="popup">Please login</a>


            <h:outputText id="greeting" value="Welcome, you have logged in" rendered="#{sessionScope.login == null ? false : true}"/>

            <div id="login" data-role="popup">

            <h:inputText value="#{requestScope.userName}"/>
            <h:inputHidden value="#{requestScope.password}"/>
            <h:commandButton value="login" action="#{loginBacking.processLogin}">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render="greeting"/>
            </h:commandButton>

            </div>

</h:form>
```

Obviously the above markup will not send the user input to the server, because jQuery Mobile popup needs `<h:form/>` tag inside popup. But if I put the `<h:form/>` tag inside popup, I cannot use `<f:ajax render="greeting"/>` (because the id "greeting" left outside).

How can I overcome this issue **without using boilerplate Javascript codes**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use absolute client IDs in `<f:ajax render>`. If you start with the JSF `NamingContainer` separator character, which defaults to `:`, then it will be resolved relative to the `UIViewRoot`. So you can just use `render=":greeting"`.

You've by the way another problem. You cannot update components in JS/Ajax/client side which are by itself *not* rendered in JSF/server side, simply because there's then nothing in the HTML DOM tree which can be referenced and updated. You need to wrap the `<h:outputText id="greeting">` in another component which is *always* rendered.

So, all with all, this should do for you:

```
<a href="#login" data-rel="popup">Please login</a>

<h:panelGroup id="greeting">
    <h:outputText value="Welcome, you have logged in" rendered="#{login != null}"/>
</h:panelGroup>

<div id="login" data-role="popup">
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText value="#{requestScope.userName}"/>
        <h:inputHidden value="#{requestScope.password}"/>
        <h:commandButton value="login" action="#{loginBacking.processLogin}">
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":greeting"/>
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

*(note that I have simplified the EL expression in the `rendered` attribute, it makes no sense to use a conditional operator to return boolean results while the expression by itself already returns a boolean result; I'd myself have preferred `rendered="#{not empty login}"` by the way)*

#### See also:

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier)
- [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w)

Comment: This has been a long term problem for me & solved now. Thanks very much. Thanks again for the tips regarding short and clean EL as well.