# h:inputText is not ajax-rendered on change of h:selectOneMenu

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have this code which is used to select how many rows to display in jsf table:

```
<!-- Set rows per page -->
<h:outputLabel for="rowsPerPage" value="Rows per page" />
<h:inputText id="rowsPerPage" value="#{AccountsController.rowsPerPage}" size="3" maxlength="3" />
<h:commandButton styleClass="bimage" value="Set" action="#{AccountsController.pageFirst}" >
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>&nbsp;
<h:message for="rowsPerPage" errorStyle="color: red;" />
```

I want to edit the code this way: I want to replace the code with `h:selectOneManu` and option to insert custom value with AJAX support:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="setrows" value="#{AccountsController.rowsPerPage}" converter="javax.faces.Integer" maxlength="3">                                    
    <f:selectItem itemValue="10" itemLabel="10" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="50" itemLabel="50" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="100" itemLabel="100" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="500" itemLabel="500" />                                    
    <f:selectItem itemValue="332" itemLabel="Custom" />
    <f:ajax render="customrowperpage" />
</h:selectOneMenu>&nbsp;
<h:inputText id="customrowperpage" value="#{AccountsController.rowsPerPage}" rendered="#{AccountsController.rowsPerPage == '332'}" required="true" />
```

But for some reason the code is not working. Can you help me to find the problem. Also I want to update AJAX functionality when I select number from the `h:selectOneMenu` list AJAX call to update the form.

Comment: If your component has the `rendered` attribute set to false, you can't update it later. You should wrap your `<h:inputText id="customrowperpage">` inside another UI component (like `<h:panelGrid>`) and rerender the container.

Comment: I tested your proposal - it's not working. I will make it more simple. How I can rewrite the source code so when I select the rows from the `h:selectOnemenu` AJAX call updates the number of rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems.

First, as JavaScript runs in the client side, you can't ajax-update a JSF component which isn't rendered to the client side. There's then simply nothing in the HTML DOM tree which JavaScript can select, manipulate and replace. You should instead ajax-update a JSF component which is *always* rendered to the client side.

```
<h:panelGroup id="customrowperpage">
    <h:inputText value="#{AccountsController.rowsPerPage}" required="true" 
        rendered="#{AccountsController.rowsPerPage == '332'}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

See also [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w)

Second, an `Integer` **never** [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) a `String`. You're in the `rendered` attribute testing `Integer rowsPerPage` against `String '332'`. Remove those singlequotes to make it a fullworthy number.

```
<h:panelGroup id="customrowperpage">
    <h:inputText value="#{AccountsController.rowsPerPage}" required="true" 
        rendered="#{AccountsController.rowsPerPage == 332}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: I updated the code it works now. Thank you! May I ask you one more thing: I want when I select number from the `h:selectOneMenu` to update the table rows. Using the original code how I can update the code?

Comment: Just set/add its client ID in `<f:ajax render>`. You can if necessary execute a bean method beforehand by `<f:ajax listener>`.

Comment: Hi BalusC, I am following your suggestion with <f:ajax render="id1 id2" with listener="#{handler.onChanged}", but it is refreshing only id1. Both ids are assigned to two input text boxes in the same form as of <h:SelectOneMenu> and both of them has disabled attribute bound to getter boolean methods. I noticed this behavior only in IE 9 but works on other browsers like IE8 and latest versions of FireFox, Chrome and Safari. Can you help me to find the problem.

Comment: I took a notice in IE9 I render (for selectOneMenu) at higher level id for <h:panelGroup> and it works, but doesn't work with two inputText box ids.