# Toggle rendering of image with ajax?

Tags: ajax, jsf, facelets

How can I show an image depending on a boolean status variable that is triggered by a button? I do not want that entire page to reload, but just that specific image.

Facelets page:

```
 </h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="test" action="#{bean.toggleStatus}">
        <f:ajax render="image"/>
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:graphicImage id="image" value="status.gif" rendered="#{bean.status}"/>
 </h:form>
```

Backing class:

```
    class Bean {

        private boolean status = false;

        public void toggleStatus() {
            status = true;
        }

        //getter, setter
    }
```

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: Try to put a placeholder around h:graphicImage and rerender that placeholder instead of image itself. Keep the rendered attribute on h:graphicImage.

Comment: Yes I see the image without rendered attribute. If I surround it with `<h:panelGroup>` it does not work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't ajax-update a HTML element which is not rendered to the HTML side. Wrap it in a component which is always rendered and update it instead.

E.g.

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="test" action="#{bean.toggleStatus}">
        <f:ajax render="image"/>
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:panelGroup id="image">
        <h:graphicImage value="status.gif" rendered="#{bean.status}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

#### See also:

- [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w)