# Conditionally rendering a dataTable

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces

I have a `<rich:dataTable>` in JSF page.

```
<rich:dataTable id="transactionTable" rendered="#{tellerBean.userTransactions.size() > 0}"
    value="#{tellerBean.userTransactions}" var="transaction">
```

When I press a search button, the backing list gets filled and I re-render the table. However this does not work, because the `rendered` attribute is server side and the grid never gets converted to HTML in the first place so re-rendering fails. How can I have the grid to be hidden when the backing list is of 0 size, and shown when the list size is > 0?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a component which is always rendered and update it instead.

```
<h:panelGroup id="transactionTableGroup">
    <rich:dataTable ... rendered="#{not empty tellerBean.userTransactions}">

    </rich:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>
```

*(note that I improved the EL expression in the `rendered` attribute as well; yours was clumsy and would only produce a XML syntax error when using Facelets instead of legacy JSP)*

#### See also:

- [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w)

Comment: @BalausC - As always you are a life saver. Thanks.