# Render a p:column with ajax primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Usig this element

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="selempaque" value="#{mbcompletado.empaque}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Si" itemValue="true"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="false"/>
    <p:ajax update="colEmp"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

I want to render a

`<p:column id="colEmp" rendered="#{mbcompletado.empaque}"> .... </p:column>`

But it does not change the render until I refresh the page. I want to use the Radio value to either show or hide the column.

Using primefaces and glassfish
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS/Ajax will only update elements which are **already** present in the HTML DOM tree. JS basically does first a `document.getElementById(clientId)` to obtain the to-be-updated element and then replaces the whole node with the new node retrieved from ajax response. JS/Ajax can't magically show/update elements which are never been rendered to the HTML output. You basically need to update a parent component which is *always* rendered and thus guaranteed to be present in the HTML DOM tree.

Assuming that the parent component is a `<p:dataTable>`,

```
<p:dataTable id="tableId" ...>
```

then you need to alter the `update` attribute accordingly:

```
<p:ajax update="tableId" />
```

#### See also:

- [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w)

Comment: I used a panelGrid, just updating that element solve the problem, thanks man :)