# JSF: PanelGrid won't render

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, rendering

I've got a checkbox with an ajax event, upon changing the value, the checkbox will change a boolean in my bean. This ajax event should also render a panelGrid with attribute `rendered="#{!*the bean's boolean*}"`. This means that the panelGrid should be visible when unchecked, and visible when checked. The boolean will be set to false by default (by @PostConstruct).

This is the corresponding code snippet:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="useAddress" value="#{handleOrder.useAddress}">
    <f:ajax event="change" execute="useAddress" render="outputAddress" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<h:panelGrid id="outputAddress" rendered="#{!handleOrder.useAddress}" columns="2" width="468px">
(...)
```

This snippet is surrounded by a `<h:form />` tag.
My `getUseAddress()` and `setUseAddress()` will be executed upon valuechange.

My question is, **why is my panelGrid always visible**?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't point with `f:ajax` on elements that got `rendered` attribute , cause when those elements wont be rendered it would be impossible for `f:ajax` to find them.

`f:ajax` must point on element that is present in the generated HTML DOM tree and when the `rendered` attribute of some JSF element equals `false` that element wont be even present in the HTML DOM tree

Change your code into this

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="useAddress" value="#{handleOrder.useAddress}">
    <f:ajax event="change" render="outputAddressWrapper" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

no need for the `execute="useAddress"`  cause the default of `execute` is `@this` anyway

```
<h:panelGroup id="outputAddressWrapper">
    <h:panelGrid id="outputAddress" rendered="#{!handleOrder.useAddress} columns="2" width="468px">
        ...
```

You say that your *panelGrid always visible* , what is the scope of your bean ? Make it at least `@ViewScoped`

Comment: This would lead to the problem you're describing, I think you mean the id of `ajax render` should be on the outer panel and the rendered attribute on the inner panel, right?