# why JSF 2.0 "rendered" does not work without refreshing the page?

Tags: jsf, render

When I click a method to render a part of the page, it does not change anything until I manually refresh the page.

Here is the bean:

```
boolean showPage = true;

public boolean getShowPage(){
    return showPage;
}
```

Here is the view:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Click" action="#{bean.hideContents()}" />
</h:form>

<p:panel rendered="#{bean.showPage}">
    Contents 
</p:panel>
```

The panel gets hidden when I manually refresh the page, otherwise it does not.
How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: "rendered " does not work,,until I refresh the page

Comment: Please read [Information to provide when asking JSF questions](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) from our JSF wiki page

Answer (score 6):

You need to update a parent component of the conditionally rendered component. You can do that by specifying its client ID in the `update` attribute of the `<p:commandButton>`:

```html
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Click" action="#{bean.hideContents}" update=":panel" />
</h:form>

<h:panelGroup id="panel">
    <p:panel rendered="#{bean.showPage}">
        Contents 
    </p:panel>
</h:panelGroup>
```

#### See also:

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier)
- [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w)