# Components value lost during ajax update

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 3.3.1 and JSF 2.0 and server used is Oracle Weblogic 11gR1

Below is my code.

```
<p:panel id="personDetailsPanelId" header="#{msg.personDetails}">  

            <!-- Radio Button -->  
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" style="align:center">  
                <h:outputText value="#{msg.accountCategory}" />  
                <p:spacer width="10px" />  
                <p:selectOneRadio id="singleJointAccountRadioId"  
                    layout="horizontal"  
                    value="#{captureAccountDetailBackingBean.accountCategory}">  
                    <f:selectItems  
                        value="#{captureAccountDetailBackingBean.accountcategoryList}">  
                    </f:selectItems>  
                    <p:ajax process="@this" event="change" update="@form"  
                        partialSubmit="true" />  
                </p:selectOneRadio>  
            </h:panelGrid>  

            <p:spacer height="30px;" />  

            <h:panelGrid id="accountDetailsId" columns="3">  
                <h:panelGrid id="firstAccountHolderId" columns="2"  
                    styleClass="float-left ">  
                    <p:graphicImage  
                        value="/com/cas/pages/common/images/person_icon.jpg" />  
                    <h:outputText value="#{msg.firstAccountHolder}" />  

                    <!-- Person Name -->  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{msg.nameofPerson}" />  
                        <span style="color: red;">*</span>  
                    </h:panelGrid>  
                    <p:inputText  
                        value="#{captureAccountDetailBackingBean.accountHolder1.personName}"  
                        size="25" required="true" />  

                    <!-- Person Address -->  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{msg.address}" />  
                        <span style="color: red;">*</span>  
                    </h:panelGrid>  
                    <p:inputTextarea  
                        value="#{captureAccountDetailBackingBean.accountHolder1.personAddress}"  
                        rows="3" autoResize="false" required="true" />  

                    <!-- DOB -->  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{msg.dateOfBirth}" />  
                        <span style="color: red;">*</span>  
                    </h:panelGrid>  
                    <p:calendar  
                        value="#{captureAccountDetailBackingBean.accountHolder1.personDOB}"  
                        navigator="true" showOn="button" size="6" required="true"  
                        pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />  

                    <!-- Age -->  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{msg.age}" />  
                        <span style="color: red;">*</span>  
                    </h:panelGrid>  
                    <p:inputText  
                        value="#{captureAccountDetailBackingBean.accountHolder1.personAge}"  
                        size="2" required="true" />  

                </h:panelGrid>  

                <p:spacer width="130px;" />  

                <h:panelGrid id="secondAccountHolderId" columns="2"  
                    styleClass="float-left"  
                    rendered="#{captureAccountDetailBackingBean.accountCategory eq 'Joint'}">  
                    <p:graphicImage  
                        value="/com/cas/pages/common/images/person_icon.jpg" />  
                    <h:outputText value="#{msg.secondAccountHolder}" />  

                    <!-- Person Name -->  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{msg.nameofPerson}" style="font-size:15px;" />  
                        <span style="color: red;">*</span>  
                    </h:panelGrid>  
                    <p:inputText  
                        value="#{captureAccountDetailBackingBean.accountHolder2.personName}"  
                        styleClass="inputText-style" size="25" required="true" />  

                    <!-- Person Address -->  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{msg.address}" />  
                        <span style="color: red;">*</span>  
                    </h:panelGrid>  
                    <p:inputTextarea  
                        value="#{captureAccountDetailBackingBean.accountHolder2.personAddress}"  
                        rows="3" autoResize="false" styleClass="inputText-style"  
                        size="25" required="true" />  

                    <!-- DOB -->  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{msg.dateOfBirth}" />  
                        <span style="color: red;">*</span>  
                    </h:panelGrid>  
                    <p:calendar  
                        value="#{captureAccountDetailBackingBean.accountHolder2.personDOB}"  
                        navigator="true" showOn="button" size="6"  
                        styleClass="inputText-style" required="true" />  

                    <!-- Age -->  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{msg.age}" />  
                        <span style="color: red;">*</span>  
                    </h:panelGrid>  
                    <p:inputText  
                        value="#{captureAccountDetailBackingBean.accountHolder2.personAge}"  
                        size="2" styleClass="inputText-style" required="true" />  

                </h:panelGrid>  
            </h:panelGrid>  

            <div style="clear: both;" />  
</p:panel>
```

Backing bean code:

```
public class CaptureAccountDetailBackingBean {  

    // For Radio Button  
SelectItem[] accountcategoryList = {new SelectItem("Single", "Single"), new SelectItem("Joint","Joint")};  

String accountCategory;  

    AccountHolderDetailVO accountHolder1 = new AccountHolderDetailVO();  

AccountHolderDetailVO accountHolder2 = new AccountHolderDetailVO();  

    // setter and getters  
}
```

AccountHolderDetailVO

```
public class AccountHolderDetailVO {  

    String personName;  
    String personAge;  
    Date personDOB;   
    String personAddress;  

    // getter and setter  
}
```

By default, radio button selected is "Single". And "secondAccountHolderId" panelgrid is displayed when user click on "Joint" radio button.

When I enter any values in the "firstAccountHolderId" or "secondAccountHolderId" panelgrid and change the radio button, the entered values are lost.

Comment: What is the scope of your backing bean? What do you mean "lost"? Lost to what? a backing bean method? an ajax based update? Your incredibly large `<h:form/>` with so many components in it will lead to slow responses and general heartache when debugging your JSF view. Break it up into smaller chunks with smaller forms.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here,

```
<p:ajax process="@this" event="change" update="@form" partialSubmit="true" />
```

you're basically telling JSF to submit (process) only the current field (and thus *not* all other fields of the form!) and then to re-render (update) the *entire* form (and thus including all other fields which were not been submitted/processed!).

So, all other fields are simply redisplaying the initial values from the bean instead of the values which were been entered but not submitted.

You need to change `update="@form"` accordingly that it only updates the components which *really* needs to be updated based on the change of the radio button. E.g.

```
<p:ajax process="@this" event="change" update="secondAccountHolder" partialSubmit="true" />  
...
<h:panelGroup id="secondAccountHolder">
    <h:panelGrid id="secondAccountHolderId" columns="2"  
                styleClass="float-left"  
                rendered="#{captureAccountDetailBackingBean.accountCategory eq 'Joint'}">  
        ...
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGroup>
```

#### See also:

- [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w)