# PrimeFaces SelectOneMenu ajax rendering

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

What was wrong in my program? I think everything is fine. My `changeKeyValue` method get the selected value 'REFERENCE' and set `true` boolean value into `showReference`.
But, my page cannot render `h:panelGroup` if I use `update="targetPanel"` in `p:ajax`.
It can render `h:panelGroup` when I use `update="entryForm"`.

**What I am missing?**

mypage.xhtml

```
<h:form id="entryForm">
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{MyBean.keyFactorValue}" required="true" style="width:257px;" id="keyFactorValue">
            <f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.selectItemList}" var="type" itemLabel="#{type.label}" itemValue="#{type}"/>  
            <p:ajax listener="#{MyBean.changeKeyValue}" update="targetPanel" event="change"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <h:panelGroup id="targetPanel" rendered="#{MyBean.showReference}">
            .......
        </h:panelGroup>

</h:form>
```

KeyFactorValue.java

```
public enum KeyFactorValue {
    REFERENCE("Reference"), FORM_TO("From-To"), FIXED("Fixed");

    private String label;

    private KeyFactorValue(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

MyBean.java

```
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
@Name("MyBean")
public class MyBean {
    private boolean showReference;

    public boolean isShowReference() {
        return showReference;
    }

    public KeyFactorValue[] getSelectItemList() {
        return KeyFactorValue.values();
    }

    public void changeKeyValue(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {
        KeyFactorValue type = keyFactor.getKeyFactorValue();
        System.out.println("Selected KeyFactorValue : " + type);
        switch(type) {
            case REFERENCE :{
                showReference = true;
                break;
            }
            default :{
                showReference = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't ajax-update an element in HTML which isn't rendered by JSF. JavaScript (the code behind ajax) wouldn't be able to find it by `document.getElementById()` in order to replace its content.

You can only ajax-update an element in HTML which is always rendered by JSF. Wrap the conditionally rendered component in another component which is always rendered and ajax-update it instead.

```html
<h:panelGroup id="targetPanel">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{MyBean.showReference}">
        ...
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

#### See also:

- [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w/9010771#9010771)