# p:commandButton rendered property doesn't update with ajax

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14980749/216161) I got that:

> You can only ajax-update a component which is always rendered (i.e.
>   when it does not have a rendered attribute).

But I tried this code and ajax-update doesn't work for me, I need to refresh the browser to see the changed button. What am I doing wrong?

```
<p:outputPanel id="buttonArea">
    <p:panel styleClass="button-area" 
             rendered="#{user != null and loginManager.profile.id != userPage.profile.id}">
        <h:form>
             <p:commandButton styleClass="button-flat" action="#{userPage.followUser}"
                              value="Follow" rendered="#{!userPage.followed}" update="buttonArea"/>
             <p:commandButton styleClass="button-flat" action="#{userPage.unfollowUser}"
                              value="Unfollow" rendered="#{userPage.followed}" update="buttonArea"/>
        </h:form>
    </p:panel>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Edit:

I tried the solution from the possible duplicated question and it doesn't work either for me, I'm doing something wrong that it's not explained there, I tried with the ajax tag, the id in html is exactly 'buttonArea' but I even tried with and without colon when I reference the id, I tried with fragments...

Comment: How can it be a duplicate if I'm doing what the answer proposes?, I reference a parent component

Comment: Yes the action is invoked, the database is updated, and if I refresh the browser the change is visible. Nothing at all in the console.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score -2):

Your commandButtons need their own ids. Update them instead of the panel.

Comment: Have you tried this? You cannot update elements with a dynamic rendered attribute directly.

Comment: at least not from 'hidden' to 'visible' (the other way around works or when they stay visible)