# show a button after an selectItem with jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need same help, i want to show a button when i select an Item from a , this is my code:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{managedBeanProjects.etat}">
<f:selectItems value="#{managedBeanProjects.statueOptions}">
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

I want to show this button, in default it will be disabled

```
<p:commandButton id="buttonStatue" value="ok" 
     update=":form1:growl :form1:pTest" icon="ui-icon-check" />
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let the button's `rendered` attribute evaluate `true` when `#{managedBeanProjects.etat}` is not empty. You can use `<f:ajax>` to ajaxically update the HTML representation on change of the dropdown. Note that you should ajax-update the button's parent as it's not possible to ajax-update a component which is by itself never rendered in first place.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{managedBeanProjects.etat}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{managedBeanProjects.statueOptions}">
    <f:ajax render="buttonStatueParent" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:panelGroup id="buttonStatueParent">
    <p:commandButton id="buttonStatue" value="ok" 
        update=":form1:growl :form1:pTest" icon="ui-icon-check"
        rendered="#{not empty managedBeanProjects.etat}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

#### See also:

- [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w/9010771#9010771)