# Parts which are ajax-rendered after actions doesn't work fine unless you reload the page

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, rendering

The fist time I go to the JSF page and I make an action for rendering some parts of the page, those parts are not rendering anymore. However, if you reload the page, thats areas are rendering fine.

For me, it seems that first time the page is constructed the ids are not prepended correctly. That causes the Jboss server to ignore every posted value because it cannot find a concurrent element in the site.
Reloading the page solves the problem with the false prepending of the ids.

I don't know because this, someone got the same problem? I have tried to solve it, but I was impossible.

Here you have the code:

```
<h:form id="select" styleClass="applic_filterside" binding="#{companyOverview2.selectForm}">
            <a4j:region>
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="applic_filter_selectrow">
                    <tibuga:selectManyCheckbox label="Branche:" valueBean="#{companyOverview2}" valueProperty="selectedSectorID" 
                        id="selSec" items="#{generalData.allSectors}" itemValue="#{c.id}" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.name}" width="174"
                        showButtonsSelectAll="false" display="none">
                            <a4j:ajax event="click" onbegin="submitSearch();"></a4j:ajax>                   
                    </tibuga:selectManyCheckbox>
                </h:panelGroup>

                <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="applic_filter_selectrow">
                    <a4j:commandLink action="#{companyOverview2.filterSearchEntrys()}" onclick="flushInputs(this);" oncomplete="turnInputs(document.getElementById('select:button'));" 
                        render="companyTableNew" execute="@form" limitRender="true" id="button">
                        <h:graphicImage value="/resources/images/fields/filter.png" />
                    </a4j:commandLink>
                </h:panelGroup>
                </a4j:region>

            </h:form>

<h:panelGroup  id="companyTableNew" >   
            <h:form>
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="applic_filter_countrow">
                    <h:outputText value="Treffer: #{companyOverview2.count()} Unternehmen" />
            </h:panelGroup>
                <a4j:region>
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="cont" styleClass="applic_applicants">
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="top_line">
                        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="sectors">
                            <h:outputText value="Branche" />
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="location">
                            <h:outputText value="Standort" />
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="size">
                            <h:outputText value="Größe" />
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </h:panelGroup>                 
                    <ui:repeat value="#{companyOverview2.filteredCompanysNew}" var="a">
                        <tibuga:singleCompanyEntry entry="#{a}" />
                    </ui:repeat>
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="companys_actions">
                        <a4j:commandLink value="weitere Unternehmen anzeigen ..." action="#{companyOverview2.showMore()}" render="companyTableNew" rendered = "#{companyOverview2.showMoreLink}"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGroup>
                </a4j:region>
            </h:form>
            </h:panelGroup>
```

The problem is that the first time that you go to the page, you can see the results correctly, but if you make a query the datas from CompanyTableNew are wrong, but reloading the page all is right.

Comment: You should provide some view code, I suspect that you are updating components that are not rendered ie : `rendered="#{bean.someGetter}"` that is initially false.

Comment: So, your bean is session scoped and you're referencing components which have by itself `rendered` attribute set instead of their parents? That are at least 2 mistakes. Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w/