# Why is actionListener not being call after ajax:update and button not being rendered

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to get a firm grasp on `ajax` but I'm afraid I'm at a lost. The code below renders the `Wait` button after clicking on the `Join` button. `Join` button's `actionListener` also gets called the first time. Then, after clicking on `Wait`, the `Join` button gets rendered but `Wait` button's `actionListener` is not called. Finally, when you click on `Join` nothing happens. This is a slight variation (I'm hoping) of this question (in case any of you saw something similar)

[commandButton inactive after ajax rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506091/commandbutton-inactive-after-ajax-rendering/17514476#comment25483956_17514476)

If this is a duplicate question I'm sorry. If BalusC answered this already from the question I posted, I'm frankly not understanding the cause. I'm at the point where nothing makes sense anymore. I'm sure it's silly but can someone please explain what is happening ?

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton id="Join" actionListener = "#{connexion.joinWaitingList}"
                     update="@form" rendered="#{connexion.renderJoinButton}"
                     value="Join"/>
    <p:commandButton id="leave" actionListener = "#{connexion.leaveWaitingList}" 
                     update="@form" rendered="#{connexion.renderWaitButton}" 
                     value="Wait"/>
</h:form>
```

The java code

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Connexion implements java.io.Serializable {
    private boolean renderJoinButton; 
    private boolean renderWaitButton; 

    public Connexion() {
        renderJoinButton = true; 
        renderWaitButton = false; 
    }

    public boolean isRenderJoinButton() {
        return renderJoinButton;
    }

    public void setRenderJoinButton(boolean renderJoinButton) {
        this.renderJoinButton = renderJoinButton;
    }

    public boolean isRenderWaitButton() {
        return renderWaitButton;
    }

    public void setRenderWaitButton(boolean renderWaitButton) {
        this.renderWaitButton = renderWaitButton;
    }

    public void joinWaitingList() {
        System.out.println("Waiting list joined"); 
        renderJoinButton = false; 
        renderWaitButton = true; 
    }

    public void leaveWaitingList() {
        System.out.println("Waiting list abandoned");
        renderJoinButton = true; 
        renderWaitButton = false; 
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I am using JSF 2.2 with PrimeFaces 3.5

**UPDATE #2**

This seems to work with JSF 2.1 and 2.0.10. It doesn't work with JSF 2.2. I have posted this issue on Primefaces forum. I'll update this post once I get a reply from them.

**UPDATE #3**

Thanks to jhond, I was made aware of a [bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2912). 
Also, one of the primefaces community members got back to me and said "only latest snapshot is kind of compatible".

Comment: Looks like you adapted the code based on that question. Note that BalusC uses a `<h:panelGroup>` in the answer since *you basically need to wrap conditionally rendered JSF components in a component whose HTML representation is always rendered and then reference it instead in the ajax update* (quoting from BalusC's answer).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza From the OP code his form also had a condition for rendering attached to it (I think).

Comment: Check BalusC's answer code, not just OP's.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Ok, let me take a closer look.

Comment: I tested and is working fine with jsf 2.0.10 and primefaces 3.5 (IE 8.0.6). Try working with your code in a new project and test your xhtml file. Do you have nested forms? (using a template maybe)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I feel silly not understanding this, I'm sorry :( I really don't get it. BalusC's code is updating a panel right ? Mines is updating the form and not a particular button. So am I not following what he sais by referencing the form in the update ? The form in my case is already in the DOM therefore I'm just updating it. Just like he is doing with the panel.

Comment: @danRod Really ? And you were getting an output for each button click and they were rendering fine every time ? I was using JSF 2.2 I guess I should have mentioned that, didn't think it was needed though sorry.

Comment: @danRod No nested forms, no templates. That's the entire code minus the library declarations in the xhtml (also using `<h:head>`)

Comment: @danRod I think you are right. I am able to get it working with JSF 2.1. I need to be absolutely sure. Give me a couple of hours and I'll give you an update. If you turn out to be correct, I will let you know. You can then feel free to post it as an actual answer and I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Do your tests first, and let me know.

Comment: Since you say you're using JSF 2.2, please note that you should use CDI annotations instead of old JSF ones. This means, use `@Named @ViewScoped` and verify that @ViewScoped` comes from `javax.faces.view`package. More info: [CDI compatible @ViewScoped](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#1087)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It comes from it, I'm sure. I also tried using CDI only (`no javax.faces.bean.*`) and still getting the same problem. I don't want to jump the gun and say it's a bug but it's looking like it *could* be...Not sure if this should be filed with the primefaces people or JSF.

Comment: @danRod Tested with JSF 2.2 `@Named` and `@ManagedBean` still issues. JSF 2.1 no issues. However, I can't say for certain it's a bug. Looking at the forums I'm seeing primefaces 4.0 is what is intended to be used with JSF 2.2 and also I'm not seeing any bug reports for my problem. I highly doubt I'm the first person this happens to, so to be on the safe side just say it works with an earlier version I guess. Thanks a lot for taking the extra time to test this !

Comment: @Andy changing versions **is definitely not a valid answer**.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza But he went so far as to test it. It could be a bug. I posted it on the primefaces forum. I don't want him to get in trouble/downvoted because of me though. What should I do ? I wrestled with this all day and he was the only one who found out the problem.

Comment: @Andy if its a bug, then it should be reported. By just changing the version without any proper explanation, that's not an answer, just *try this because the other doesn't work at the moment not for you nor me* =\

Comment: @danRod I don't want you to get more downvotes because of me. I guess it's not considered an answer because you didn't find the root cause. Sorry man. I guess you should delete it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza But I swear I've seen post where people state that it's a possible bug and it was reported. You're right though. I will update my post and if he wants to delete his answer then so be it I guess. Apologies for being careless.

Comment: @Andy one more thing, remove the mark of accepted answer from the current answer since it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm thinking about it. I'm not trying to be difficult but his answer did solve my problem...One sec.

Comment: @danRod Darn it! He does bring a valid point *try this because the other doesn't work at the moment not for you nor me =\*. Since we're not sure it's a bug I can't say with 100% certainty that it's valid. I feel bad for this sorry again.

Comment: Don't worry I deleted already. Good to know you solve your issue.

Comment: You can also check if this fits your issue: [bug1](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2912). Also I am sure that I've seen a bug with JSF 2.2 that had a proposed workaround like `render="@form a_panel_that_is_not_being_rendered_id"` but I cannot find it, if you try it let us know if it works. This one also fits [bug2](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2755)

Comment: @johnd Thanks a lot. I know what you're talking about. I didn't make much of it last night. I'm going to try this workaround.

Comment: @johnd I check out bug1 and the constructor does get called multiple times. bug2 I'm not sure what to make of it since I'm using Chrome. Also the update stops occuring after the 3rd time whereas this one doesn't seem to happen at all (I think that's what I read). As for the workaround, no luck there either. One member from the primefaces community got back to me and said only the latest snapshot is *somewhat* compatible  with JSF 2.2.

Comment: JSF2.2 has quite a few bugs. If you want to spend more time on this (which sounds like a bug), you could put a breakpoint to your `FacesServlet.service` method. Check the request parameters and see that JS is actually sending the correct render/execute. A [bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2871) I raised (which has to do with multipart forms) messes up the ajax request parameters. I can see how this would fit your problem (I am not using primefaces so don't know how they interact with mojarra JSF.js)
PS. I would also remove primefaces and make sure that it works with native JSF

Comment: @jhond 2.2 is too much of a hassle right now. I'm going back to 2.1. I give up. It sort of works with native jsf but I have to click the first button twice. At first I thought it was a reported bug but now I'm not so sure. Ill check again.