# f:ajax render form component

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I want to render a single component *(h:selectManyCheckbox)* inside a form based on a check-box that I select or not.

```
<h:form> 
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.var}">
        <f:ajax event="click" render="employeeCheckboxes" />
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

    <h:selectManyCheckbox 
        id="employeeCheckboxes"
        value="#{bean.checkboxes}"
        rendered="#{var}">
    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
</h:form>
```

However, the component isn't re-rendered on selecting or deselecting the check-box. I can however re-render the whole form but I don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference a component in `<f:ajax render>` which is in first place never rendered in HTML output. The `<f:ajax render>` uses under the covers JavaScript `document.getElementById()` to find the HTML element in order to update it with the new HTML structure from the ajax response. However, if a JSF component is in first place never rendered  in HTML output, then JavaScript can't find it anywhere either.

You need to wrap it in another component which is **always** rendered.

```
<h:form> 
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.var}">
        <f:ajax render="employeeCheckboxesGroup" />
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

    <h:panelGroup id="employeeCheckboxesGroup">
        <h:selectManyCheckbox 
            id="employeeCheckboxes"
            value="#{bean.checkboxes}"
            rendered="#{bean.var}">
        </h:selectManyCheckbox>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

*(note that I removed `event="click"` as it's the default already)*

#### See also:

- [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w/)

Answer (score -1):

Hi i think you missed managed bean name in

> rendered attribute

of checkbox tag.

Comment: Please recreate and test the problem locally if you can't tell from top of head for sure.

Comment: @BalusC ok Mr. BalusC

Comment: @BalusC can u please refer this question and give the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907770/when-to-use-colon-in-rendering-in-jsf-components