# How to submit form, from p:selectBooleanCheckbox change event

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using primefaces and working on a complex form. I need to hide a part of the form, depending on the value of a checkbox

```
    <p:selectBooleanButton id="input1" .... />
<p:inputText id="input2" />


<!-- the boolean checkbox -->
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkBox1" value="#{bbean.someBoolValue}" >
    <p:ajax event="change" update=":#{p:component('someParentcComponentsId')}" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<!-- some input fields here. These will be rendered depending checkBox1 value -->
<p:panel rendered="#{bbean.someBoolValue}" id="hiddingPanel">   
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" >

        <p:inputText id="input3" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
```

So far, I've made that work, so when `checkBox1` is clicked, `hiddingPanel` is getting shown or hidden. But there's a catch:  the values of every input in that form ( e.g. `input1`, `input2` ) are lost, since the 'change' ajax event is not submitting their values.

How could I make sure that **all** input values are submitted before updating the form ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make sure that you update **only** the section which *really* needs to be updated.

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkBox1" value="#{bbean.someBoolValue}" >
    <p:ajax event="change" update="hiddingPanel" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<!-- some input fields here. These will be rendered depending checkBox1 value -->
<p:panel id="hiddingPanel">   
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{bbean.someBoolValue}">

        <p:inputText id="input3" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
```

Note that I moved `rendered` to its immediate child, for the reasons explained here: [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w)

Comment: Thank you BalusC. for your answer. So there is no way to (partially) submit the form ? If that's the case, then I should indeed update a part of the form, just to avoid losing unsubmitted changes.

Comment: Uh, I just answered exactly how to acheive that? Or do you mean to partially process a form? If so, you can control that with `process` attribute, but this defaults in case of `<p:ajax>` already to `@this`.

Comment: What I really wanted was to submit the whole form. I tried 'process="@form"' and everything seems to work fine. I think this is exactly what I needed. Thanx again

Comment: Impressed by your solution..... i have wasted 4 hours to solve the problem. thanks @BalusC