# Disable if the selection box value is DOB

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Hi guys im trying to disable a selectOneRadio selection if the user have selected DOB from dropdown menu but it is still rendering the selectionOneRadio button

here is the code

```
   Please select the criteria you wish to search :

      <p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.criteria}" effect="fade"
                                 filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                                 style="width:230px" 
                                 >
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.labelUsername}" itemValue="username" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.labelFirstName}" itemValue="firstName" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.labelSurname}" itemValue="surname" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.labelGender}" itemValue="gender" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.labelDOB}" itemValue="DateOfBirth" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.labelPhone}" itemValue="telephoneNumber" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.labelEmail}" itemValue="emailAddress" />  
        <p:ajax update="searchMatch" event="valueChange"/>
      </p:selectOneMenu>




   Please select if you would like an exact or partial match

      <p:selectOneRadio id="searchMatch" value="#{bean.match}" style="width:230px" 
                                  required = "True"
                                  requiredMessage = "#{bundle.requiredMatch}"
                                  rendered="#{bean.criteria !='DateOfBirth'}">
         <f:selectItem itemLabel="Exact" itemValue="=" />  
         <f:selectItem itemLabel="Partial" itemValue="LIKE " />
      </p:selectOneRadio>
```

how can i get it so that when DateOfBirth is selected the one radio button is disabled

Comment: selectOne's are inside a form, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't ajax-update a component which is by itself conditionally rendered. The JavaScript responsible for changing the HTML DOM tree based on JSF ajax response can only *replace* HTML DOM elements, not add/remove them in their entirety.

Instead, you need to ajax-update a parent component which is **always** rendered.

```
<p:selectOneMenu ...>
    ... 
    <p:ajax update="searchMatchGroup" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<h:panelGroup id="selectMatchGroup>
    <p:selectOneRadio ... rendered="#{bean.criteria !='DateOfBirth'}">
        ...
    </p:selectOneRadio>
</h:panelGroup>
```

#### See also:

- [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w)

Answer (score -1):

You have to add a listener at change event of `<p:selectOneMenu>`. That method update a boolean property of backing managed bean. That property enable and disable the `<p:selectOneRadio>`.

As for example change your `<p:ajax>` into

```
<p:ajax update="searchMatch" listener="bean.updateRadio"/>
```

And `updateRadio` method will be :

```
public void updateRadio(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
   if(criteria ==  DOB)// check here if selected item is DOB ??
     {match=true}
   else match=false;
}
```

`match` is initialized with value `false`. I think this may solve your problem.

Comment: Listener is absolutely not required.