# JSF 2.0: Immediately render a component after hitting a radio button

Tags: ajax, jsf

When the user chooses the expert radio button, I would like to render an additional outputText with "expert" as value. I tried ajax, with event,listener and render attributes but nothing works.

This is my form:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneRadio id="rb" value="#{account.dtype}">
        <f:selectItem itemId="user" itemValue="user" itemLabel="User" />
        <f:selectItem itemId="admin" itemValue="admin" itemLabel="Admin" />
        <f:selectItem itemId="expert" itemValue="expert" itemLabel="Expert" />
        <f:ajax execute="@this" render="choice"/>
    </h:selectOneRadio>
    <br />
    <h:outputLabel id="choice" value="#{account.dtype}" rendered="#{account.dtype}=='expert'" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: With JSF 2.x, the attribute itemId is not defined in the component selectItem: your page won't work. Please add the relevant missing information

Comment: @perissf, it could actually work as non existing attributes are by default ignored. If `Account#Dtype` is an `String` with the necessary getter and setter methods, it should. Anyway, the question is lacked of resources as the managed bean being used.

Comment: Have you found the answer useful? In case it helped, mark it as answered, otherwise leave a comment so that I can improve it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you, I found the problem.

The problem was that I had the xhtml page containing the form where the body was  instead of , same thing for  instead of

I also used the click ajax event instead of "execute".

Your rectifications helped me also, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted contains several errors.

First, you have an error in the EL formula that checks `account.dtype`: everything that's out of the curly brackets is evaluated as a pure text string, therefore your formula evaluates to the string `expert=='expert'` and not to a boolean value. You have to use:

```
<h:outputLabel id="choice" value="#{account.dtype}" rendered="#{account.dtype == 'expert'}" />
```

(or use `eq` instead of `==` operator)

Second, the component to be updated must exist in the DOM tree, otherwise its rendered status cannot be updated. So, wrap it in a component which is always rendered and ajax-update it instead. For example, you can update the whole form:

```
<f:ajax execute="@this" render="@form"/>
```

Finally, although this doesn't have any effect, note that the attribute itemId is not defined in the component selectItem, and will be ignored by JSF. Your IDE should have warned you about this.

#### See also:

- [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w/9010771#9010771)