# Rich:autocomplete keep showing after rendered false

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I don't know why, but  after i set rendered false on my autocomplete the field disappear but the options don't

```
<rich:autocomplete id="#{idClassificacao}inputAutoComplete"
    value="#{campoClassificacaoBean.valorSelecionado}"
    autocompleteMethod="#{campoClassificacaoBean.autocomplete}"
    var="classe"
    autofill="false"
    minChars="2"
    mode="ajax"
    selectFirst="true"
    fetchValue="#{classe.id}"
    disabled="#{not campoClassificacaoBean.classificacaoEmEdicao}"
    onselectitem="#{onSelectItemAutoComplete}();"
    styleClass="inputClassificacao"
    layout="table"
    rendered="#{not campoClassificacaoBean.contextoConsulta}">
    <rich:column>
        <de:classeDetails classe="#{classe}" printNomePlano="true"/>
    </rich:column>
</rich:autocomplete>
```

Comment: Provide the Facelets components you need to stop rendering along with this code.

Comment: Before anything else, you should [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w)