# Make active component if check box is selected

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I want to make active h:selectOneMenu when h:selectBooleanCheckbox is selected.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{user.rememberMe}" /> I agree




<h:selectOneMenu value="#{user.favCoffee1}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Cream Latte" itemLabel="Coffee3 - Cream Latte" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Extreme Mocha" itemLabel="Coffee3 - Extreme Mocha" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Buena Vista" itemLabel="Coffee3 - Buena Vista" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

In my cases I would like to let the user to select value from h:selectOneMenu only when he has selected that here accepts web site terms.

Answer (score 2):

Just bind the `disabled` attribute of the other component to the checkbox value and let the checkbox ajax-update the other component on change.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{user.rememberMe}">
    <f:ajax render="menu" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<h:selectOneMenu id="menu" ... disabled="#{not user.rememberMe}">
    ...
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

You only need to make sure that the managed bean holding the property bound by the `disabled` (and `rendered` and `readonly`) attribute is view scoped. See also [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/)

In case you'd like to show/hide it via `rendered` attribute instead of enable/disable it via `disabled` attribute, then you need to wrap it in another component and ajax-update that wrapper instead. See also [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{user.rememberMe}" onchange="submit()"/> I agree

<h:selectOneMenu value="#{user.favCoffee1}" disabled="#{not user.rememberMe}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="Cream Latte"
                itemLabel="Coffee3 - Cream Latte" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="Extreme Mocha"
                itemLabel="Coffee3 - Extreme Mocha" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="Buena Vista"
                itemLabel="Coffee3 - Buena Vista" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
```