# Force re-evaluation of rendered property on JSF component

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

In my application, I have a phaselistener that can conditionally hide a component by setting UIComponent.setRendered(false) .

On that page, I have ajax tabs, with tab one able to influence the display of the other. So, I go to a tab, change something, come back, but there I find that the component still remembers it's unrendered state.

I guess not doing ajax for my tab navigation would solve this, but is there any other way that I can somehow force the component tree to be build up as if it was the first time?

Comment: most likely https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/ is a duplicate

Comment: Are you dealing with primefaces tabs?

Comment: No, just ajax postback with p:commandButton. We only make it look somewhat like tabs.