# selectManyCheckbox ajax listener not called

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the following code:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="contactrole"
                      value="#{contactDetail.contactRoles}"
                      required="#{}"
                      layout="grid"
                      columns="1"
                      disabled="#{!contactDetail.editMode}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{contactDetail.contactRoleItems}"/>
    <p:ajax event="change"
            process="@this"
            update="linked_relationship_detail"
            listener="#{contactDetail.doSomething()}"/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

When I select or unselect checkboxes the `doSomething()` method is executed, except when I unselect the last checkbox. So when there are no checkboxes selected this method is not called. 
When I set the required attribute to false then the method is called. Until a certain  point I understand this logic, but certain components in my view are  rendered (or not) depending if there are checkboxes selected or not. So how can I know that there are no checkboxes selected anymore?

Comment: PrimeFaces version?

Comment: I'm using Primaces 6.0

Comment: Can you try 6.1?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to render a component depending on whether or not your `p:selectManyCheckbox` have any component selected, you can simply do this:

```
... rendered="#{not empty contactDetail.contactRoles}" ...
```

Comment: You can't just do that on the `p:selectManyCheckbox`... You need to wrap it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w

Comment: The same issue still exists with this solution. Because the contactRoles list is not empty (although everything is unselected), I don't get the correct behavior.