# Re-render <h:graphicImage by <p:commandButton

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Lets assume i have next graphic image tag inside a form

```
<p:lightBox styleClass="imagebox " id="imageLightBox" rendered="true">
   <h:outputLink value="http://..../center/#{myBean.centerId}/picture" title="Bla bla bla">
       <h:graphicImage value="http://..../center/#{myBean.centerId}/picture" />
   </h:outputLink>
</p:lightBox>
```

and i have next primefaces command button

```
<p:commandButton icon="fa fa-save" value="Save" title="Save" actionListener="#{myBean.saveCenterImage()}" update="@form" >
```

So how can i re-render **graphicImage** when i click on **commandButton**.

Comment: if you're updating the form it should actually be rerendered, most likely you're missing the process="imageLightBox" or process="@form". By the way, I would remove the rendered attribute since it's always true (unless it's like that only for clarity), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w/

Comment: @MárioFernandes: process attribute is for what is processed on the server regarding submitted values. You can still update something that is **not** processed.

Comment: what did you debug? Did you check the ajax response? What does it contain? The same or a new url? Is the browser trying retrieve it? results in a 304? Please explain more

Comment: @Kukeltje you're totally correct, thanks

Comment: @MárioFernandes yes, rendered=true just for clarification (i am not use it in code) ayway i tried process="imageLightBox" and process="@form" and it doesn't work, i don't know what is the problem, actually i wrote the question so many people think with me and may any one give me a new way to do it for example may using JQuery or pure javascript or what ever (Thanks for ur reply :) )

Comment: like Kukeltje said, what's the url from the image, what do you get? 304? 404?

Comment: @MárioFernandes i am sure the url is working fine, i just change the image in destination server, but same url still valid, so i am sure no problems at all with image url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use `p:graphicImage` instead of `h:graphicImage` and set the attribute cache=false so that the browser will not cache the image.